# Indexing text content of html

Tags: c++, linux, indexing, html-parsing

I want to pull the text out of html files for indexing purposes, and do so as fast as possible. Rather than create something from scratch, I want to see how much I can find already done for me.

Currently I'm just piping the output of html2text, which works, but between being python and trying to prettify the text, I'm sure the speed could be improved.

So, with Linux/unix being priority, what (c/c++) libraries would be best suited to this kind of task?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser and others (just search!!)

Comment: I'm not exactly looking for a parser. That's as low-level as I want to go. I'm looking for recommendations for the simplest fastest way to extract the text from html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the text you can use an HTML parser like [htmlcxx](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/) or [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/). You can can also use any XML library after [tidying up](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) the HTML. For indexing the text you can use [CLucene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/).

Comment: libxml will do. Xapian is the indexer in this case.